# What's the next number in this number sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

Find the next number in this sequence:

2, 4, 8, 13, 20, 29, 41, ?

EXTENSION:
Find the number for the *n*th term in the sequence (in terms of *n*).

Hint:

> Fibonacci+Triangle

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html

Comment: The hint has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Ok, just checking

Comment: And I changed it to make it more obvious.

Comment: OEIS found [this](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+4%2C+8%2C+13%2C+20%2C+29%2C+41&language=english&go=Search) but I don't think that is what you had in mind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 57

Solution for the extension: (Thanks @PerpetualJ for MathJax)

> $$Fi. Δ.$$
>  $$1 + 1 = 2$$
>  $$1 + 3 = 4$$
>  $$2 + 6 = 8$$
>  $$3 + 10 = 13$$
>  $$5 + 15 = 20$$
>  $$8 + 21 = 29$$
>  $$13 + 28 = 41$$
>  $$21 + 36 = 57 \leftarrow (Next Term)$$
>  Round off to the nearest integer.
>  $Fi(n) = round\biggl(\frac{(-\frac{1}{\phi})^n}{\sqrt{5}}\biggr)$
>  $\Delta(n) = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$
>  $\int(n) = Fi(n) + \Delta(n) = round\biggl(\frac{(-\frac{1}{\phi})^n}{\sqrt{5}}\biggr) + \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$

Comment: Yes, good job!!

Answer (score 12):

The next number is

> $34$

The formula is

> $2^n - \dfrac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}2$

Comment: I'm thinking of a different formula and I realized this worked as well so I'll edit the question.